# When Selecting Multiple Values in Listbox getting exception Index was outside the bounds of the array in Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a multiple values in ListBox. When I am Selecting a Single Value my code is working fine.

But when I am Selecting Multiple Values it is giving me this Exception:-

**Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

My code is:

```
if (submitButton == "Enroll Trainee")
{
    if (Request.Form["NonEnroll"] != null)
    {
        int i = 0;
        string[] selected = Request.Form["NonEnroll"].Split(',');
        if (selected != null)
        {
            if (selected.Count() != 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in selected)
                {
                    enrollDetails.TraineeID = Convert.ToInt32(item[i].ToString());//Getting Exception here
                    enrollDetails.TrainerID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["user"].ToString());
                    enrollDetails.dt = DateTime.Now;
                    db.EnrollTrainee.Add(enrollDetails);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    i++;
                }

            }
        }
        populatelistbox();
        return View();
    }
}
```

During the First Iteration it is working fine and also save first iteration result in my database. But when it starts second iteration it give me the above exception

Comment: I guess you need: `enrollDetails.TraineeID = Convert.ToInt32(item);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misused the loop variable, I guess you need:

```
enrollDetails.TraineeID = Convert.ToInt32(item);
```

Let me explain why you original code `item[i].ToString()` didn't worked:

Lets assume you got the list `"2,1,3"` then with the string split you have created the array of strings : `new [] { "2", "1", "3" }`

Then in your loop

1. In the first iteration

   - **item** was `"2"`
   - **i** was `0`

   So `item[i]` resolved in `"2"[0]` which is `"2"` and it worked.
2. In the second iteration

   - **item** was `"1"`
   - **i** was `1`

   and your code resolved in `"1"[1]` which thrown an exception because `"1"` is only one character long so the Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: I didn't get your **One Character Long** point.

Comment: strings are basically array of chars. So the string `"test"` can be expressed as the array of the `'t','e','s','t'` chars. In C# all the arrays are indexed from `0`. So with the `"1"[1]` you want to get the **second** element form the char array which has only one char `'1'`.

Comment: Yeah got your point. If i'll write instead of **item** **item[0]** then I guess it will also works.